# Macro not deleting all items that meet requirement

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this very simple macro to delete all rows when Column P has a "1" or "0" and Column L contains "False".  For what ever reason, it does not seem to run continuously.  I have to repeatedly run the macro over and over to delete everything.

```
    Sub Delete_rows()

    Dim Pcell As Range
    Dim LastPCell As Long
    Range("P2", Range("P65000").End(xlUp)).Name = "LastPCell"

    For Each Pcell In Range("LastPCell")
    If Pcell <= 1 And Pcell.Offset(0, -4) = "False" Then Pcell.Offset(0, 4).EntireRow.Delete
    Next Pcell

    End Sub
```

There only about 10,000 rows so the range size should be fine.

I'm sorta dumbfound at this point, I haven't been able to trouble shoot it.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Expand on @bernie's answer

```
Sub Delete_rows()
Dim lastCell As Long, i As Integer, Pcell As Range
lastCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P65000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastCell To 2 Step -1
Set Pcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 16)
    If Pcell <= 1 And Pcell.Offset(0, -4) = "False" Then
        Pcell.Offset(0, 4).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Greetings Brad, any idea why I am get "Compiler error: Object required" and it's highlighting Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P65000").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have opened up Excel. It should compile now. The reason you were getting the error you were seeing was that I'd changed `Pcell` to be an integer while the `set` keyword is for assigning objects.